# Static Webstie - Render Dropdown Json Data

Tags: javascript, html, json, vs-web-site-project, static-pages

For static website, where we need to show dropdowns of predefined/organized json data (>50MB). Problem is Loading all the data while launching page killing user's browser (not responding). How to handle this in an effective and **cost optimized** manner?

Currently Website uses plain html and js.

**Model page looks like this:**

[image]

**Sample Json hierarchy data:**

```
{
  "level-1": [
    {
      "level-2-1": [
        {
          "level-3-2-1-1": "value1",
          "level-3-2-1-2": "value2"
        }
      ],
      "level-2-2": [
        {
          "level-3-2-2-1": "value1",
          "level-3-2-2-2": "value2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Don't. Even just parsing that much data is ridiculous.

Comment: @Ted Brownlow - Any suggestions what could be efficient of handling this?

Comment: Add a HTTP endpoint to the server that given a full path, returns the immediate options. Then, fetch() at this endpoint whenever a layer is expanded